# Javascript button click on slider change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a below javascript function which updates the display values when I move the slider. However, now I am planning to update the values only on the button click. This is the javascript function.

```
.on("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
            var $output =$(this).nextAll(".output:first");
            $output.html(data.value.toFixed(2));
            masterData[$output.attr("id").replace(/output/,"")] = data.value;
            $("#kwBody > tr").each(function() {
               var $cells = $(this).children("td");

               var found=false,count=0,currentCell;
               for (var i=0;i<masterData.length;i++) {
                 currentCell=$cells.eq(i+1);
                 found = parseInt(currentCell.text(),10) >=masterData[i];
                 currentCell.toggleClass("found",found); //add or remove class to highlight 
                 count+=found;
               }
               window.console && console.log(masterData,count);
               $(this).toggle(count==masterData.length); // show if all cells >

            });
        });
});
```

I designed a button as below.

```
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Display!</button>
```

I included the above javascript function inside myfunction(). However, the update is not happening on the button click. A working example can be found [here](http://omega.uta.edu//~rxv1100/willdoit.php).

**EDIT:**

```
  <h2>Keyword Scores</h2>
  <?php

$i = 0;
while (++$i <= $_SESSION['totalcolumns']-1) {
isset($_GET["slider$i"]) ? $rangevalue=$_GET["slider$i"] : $rangevalue="";
    $range = $_SESSION["min-column-$i"] . ',' . $_SESSION["max-column-$i"];?>
        <br><?php echo "Keyword" ?>
        <?php echo $i ?>
        <br><input type="text" data-slider="true" id="slider<?php echo $i; ?>" data-slider-range="<?php echo $range ?>" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $rangevalue; ?>" data-slider-step="1">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh">
        <?php } ?>  



<script>
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. what exactly do you want to do? As I see it, you want to set the values in the slider, and then filter the table only when you press the button. Am I right? If so, you want to apply all three slider values' to filter?

Comment: Thanks for commenting out. Yes, once I set the values in the UI filter then only I need to display the values.Yeah, I need to apply all the three values to the filter. That is already taken care by the javascript function. I need this to happen only when I press the button.

Comment: Kindly, post some markup for the sliders

Comment: I have added the code as an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an 'id' attribute to the button.  Say it is 'myButton'. Now,

1. I'm assuming that the var masterData is global
2. Change the slider listener to

   ```
   .on("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
       var $output =$(this).nextAll(".output:first");
       $output.html(data.value.toFixed(2));
       masterData[$output.attr("id").replace(/output/,"")] = data.value;   
    });
   ```
3. Create a click listener for the button

   ```
   $("#myButton").click(function (){
          $("#kwBody > tr").each(function() {
             var $cells = $(this).children("td");
             var found=false,count=0,currentCell;
              for (var i=0;i<masterData.length;i++) {
                currentCell=$cells.eq(i+1);
                found = parseInt(currentCell.text(),10) >=masterData[i];
                currentCell.toggleClass("found",found); //add or remove class to highlight 
                count+=found;
           }
          window.console && console.log(masterData,count);
          $(this).toggle(count==masterData.length); // show if all cells >

       });
   });
   ```
4. Simulate button click on each page load.

   ```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myButton").click();
    });
   ```

I haven't tried it, but hopefully, it works.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It works but the contents of the second page are still displayed only in the second page rather than getting updated in the second page. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you see the link that I had provided in my question, I have pagination in my program. I display 20 values per page initially. So if I have totally 50 values, I have 3 pages with 20 values in first 2 pages and 10 values in the final page. Suppose, after setting the slider values, I get only 15 values, I should ideally display all the 15 values in the first page rather than displaying them in 3 pages.

Comment: Oh, I see, I seem to have understood what you wanted. Perhaps calling this method every time the page loads will accomplish your need?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. Is that possible? I can share more code, if you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40385/discussion-between-anudeep-bulla-and-ram-esh)